# MySQL data load from .csv, but some data is missing! Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns

Tags: mysql, database, csv

I'm trying to load a .csv file into MySQL remotely, some of the data is loaded, but a part is missing and i'm getting a lot of warnings, the first ones are:

```
Data truncated for column 'updatedAt' at row 1 
Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns
```

My table has the following columns:

```
 id           | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment
 name         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 datavalidade | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 createdAt    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 updatedAt    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

The command i'm using is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/root/sistema/dados.csv'
INTO TABLE pergunta
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (name,datavalidade,createdAt,updatedAt);
```

This is how the .csv file looks:

```
"Wafer Bauducco triplo chocolate";"2022-04-12 00:00:00";"2021-08-26 12:49:36";"2021-08-26 12:49:36"
"Wafer Bauducco Morango";"2022-04-12 00:00:00";"2021-08-26 12:49:58";"2021-08-26 12:49:58"
"Wafer Bauducco Chocolate";"2022-05-10 00:00:00";"2021-08-26 12:50:37";"2021-08-26 12:50:37"
```

Comment: Possibly your lines are actually terminated by `\r\n`

Comment: Maybe there is a semi-colon or quote missing somewhere in the file? That can cause some values to 'shift to the left' so to speak. You could try validating it using this Notepad++ plug-in
https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint/ btw it can also just convert the data to insert statements, maybe that's easier